# android locationlistener

Tags: android

I am tring to get the location from a service and its returning null, i dont know what could be the  problem. Here my sample code below.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        locListener = new GpsLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
                locListener);
        loc = locListener.getLocation();
        showMessage("Service started");
        if (loc != null) {
            latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
        }
        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
            connectWebservice();
        }
        Log.i("trackmeservice", "service started");
    }
```

here my loc is null. Any help will be apprecited thanks;

Comment: what is GpsLocationListener? Is that your own class?

Comment: GpsLocationListener is my class which implements LocationListener

Answer (score 0):

just check, whether your gps and internet working properly or not.

Add permissions to your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
```

above the Application tag

Comment: i have added the permission and its even working fine for raise alarm function. The Raise Alarm just send the latitude and longitude only once. But i need track me service that sends the coordinates between intervals. I am using an alarm manager which seems to be working, am also using background service.